# Not understanding a regular expression in php preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, pipe

a very basic question , I don't get the point of the Pipe use in this following regular expression:

```
$menu=preg_replace("|<li><a href=\"".$base."\">(.*)</a></li>|U", "<li class=\"current\">$1</li>", $menu);
```

Of course I know they mean multiple (OR) matching, I'm not sure why the are use in that position, like at the very beginning of the regexp "|

http://www.paitadesign.com/blog/php-e-css-come-evidenziare-la-pagina-corrente-nel-menu-di-navigazione/

I'd be glad if u can help, I'm sure it's an idiot question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THe pipe is the delimiter the seperates the regex from the modifiers (usually you will see / as the delimiter but it can be whatever single character) http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php
Look there for the U modifier which is PCRE_UNGREEDY

Answer (score 1):

The letter U is a modifier for perform modifications to the behaviour of the pattern matching.

i - Ignore Case, case insensitive

U - Make search ungreedy

s - Includes New line

m - Multiple lines

x - Extended for comments and whitespace

e - Enables evaluation of replacement as PHP code. (preg_replace only)

S - Extra analysis of pattern

See more at:

http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-Regex.html

Answer (score 1):

As Kris explains it the pipe is used as delimiter and the U modifier is use to switch the quantifiers behaviour between greedy and lazy.

Note that this line could be better written like this:

```
$menu = preg_replace('~<li><a href="' . $base . '">(.*?)</a></li>~',
                     '<li class="current">$1</li>', $menu);
```